# Qual a diferença e quando usar o Flexbox ou CSS Grid?

Tags: css, css3, grid, flexbox

Primeiramente tivemos o [Flexbox](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/) como uma nova solução para a construçãod e layouts responsivos. Mais precisamente na parte de grids. Agora há pouco tempo surge o [CSS Grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/). Minha questão é: Qual a diferença dos 2 ? Quando devo usar 1 ao invés do outro ? Para a construção de grids para layouts responsivos, qual devo escolher ?

Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se usa mais o GRID para toda a página (o < body > todo). Vai dividir a página completa em linhas e células (como se fosse uma grande planilha Excel). Esse GRID foi [inter-] invenção da Microsoft. Mas a maioria dos navegadores ainda não o aceitam, somente o EDGE da MS. :/

O FLEX (display:flex) é mais usado para centralizar ou posicionar < li >´s ou < div >´s que estão dentro de uma outra div mãe (contenedor). O FLEX é o mais usado hoje (que o GRID, que praticamente está em fase de teste). Mas, atenção: FLEXBOX é uma coisa, o FLEX do display:flex (CSS) é outra coisa. Espero que você me perguntou desse último, ainda que muitos chamam o FLEX de FLEXBOX, mas não é correto: FLEXBOX é um framework. FLEX são atributos do CSS puro.

Talvez o GRID só será algo para que voltemos ao passado dos tables... Não está sendo visto como boa alternativa pela maioria.

Aquí fiz um exemplo de FLEX para centralizar linhas e colunas, usando flex:.
https://codepen.io/colombe/pen/mPmNbb

Te recomendo que leia isso: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

Comment: pergunta: o flex do css não tem suporte pra todos os navegadores, mas o flexbox tem?

Comment: Sinceramente eu não sei pq esse frame nunca usei. Mas o FLEX parece que está mais aceito.. veja isso: http://i.stack.imgur.com/azmua.png

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Fiel. Sim, não estava falando do framework. Mas sobre a questão do nome, até mesmo a W3 o chamada assim 0 https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/.

Comment: O framework flexbox utiliza os atributos chamados flexbox pra fazer essa parte de responsividade.

Comment: Grid é [suportado](https://caniuse.com/css-grid) pela maioria dos navegadores hoje em dia.

Answer (score 1):

Os propósitos de `flexbox` e `Grid-layout` são diferentes.

#### Flexbox:

O foco dele é organizar os itens em linhas ou colunas, mas seguindo o sistema de "blocos", ou seja o conteúdo será vários retângulos, um ao lado do outro, ou sobre o outro.

#### Grid-layout:

Como o nome diz, faz um grid (grade), e serve para organizar seus itens de forma mais sofisticada, onde cada um tem um comportamento independente, ocupa um número de linhas e colunas que você estipula.
Exemplo de layout que precisei fazer:
[image: grid-layout]
A versão mobile era totalmente diferente dessa, mas foi muito fácil de converter, pois, como eu disse, cada item se comporta independente, logo eu só mudei a posição de cada um deles e foi mais fácil do que usar qualquer "gambiarra".
Problema do Grid-layout é a compatibilidade com IE, funciona somente na versão 11 e não muito bem, então uso uma biblioteca mixin SASS que gera para mim.
[grid-layout-IE11](https://github.com/jomarchumi/grid-layout-IE11)